# Combine multiple arrays of elements into single jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

If I have multiple arrays of elements, what's the syntax to reference them together in order to perform an action on all elements?

```
  $b = $('.b');
  $c = $('.c');
  $($b, $c).addClass('selected'); // only selects elements in $b
```

https://codepen.io/awestmoreland/pen/eVmEZZ

I'm kicking myself because I know I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument is [context](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context), so it won't work as you expected. You can use [`add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add) method to create new combined jQuery selector.

```
$b.add($c).addClass('selected');
```

```js
var $b1 = $('.b'),
  $c1 = $('.c');

$b1.add($c1).addClass('selected');
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="b">R</div>
<div class="c">B</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `add()` method:

```
$b.add($c).addClass('selected');
```

This is obviously assuming you already have those references, otherwise you can just use a single selector separated by a comma:

```
$('.b, .c').addClass('selected');
```

Comment: Thanks. I do already have the references so I want to avoid looking them up again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.add()](https://api.jquery.com/add/), or create an array and loop ([.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)) through it.

*Note: don't make your code too complex with `.add()`, selecting by `$('.b, .c')` can be better.*

```js
//.add():
$b1 = $('.b.one');
$c1 = $('.c.one');

$($b1).add($c1).addClass('selected');

//.each():
$b2 = $('.b.two');
$c2 = $('.c.two');
$([$b2, $c2]).each(function(){
  $(this).addClass('selected');
})
```

```css
div{
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.b{
  background-color: red;
}

.c{
  background-color: blue;
}

.selected{
  background-color: purple !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>.add() :</p>
<div class="b one">R</div>
<div class="c one">B</div>

<br/><br/>

<p>.each() :</p>
<div class="b two">R</div>
<div class="c two">B</div>
```

Comment: Ah, I'd tried the array, but neglected to use .each. Good tip!

Answer (score 0):

Another Shortest way to perform:

`$('li.b, li.c').addClass('selected');`